Why is there a trailing zero at the end of Doubly-Linked Circular Linked List in C++?
I have a Data Structure problem regarding a doubly-linked circular list in C++.
I've implemented a doubly linked circular list using class templates. When testing the circular nature of the list by iterating through more elements than the list contains, I'm encountering an unexpected behavior. Here's the code I'm working with:
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "DCList.h"

int main() {
    
    DCList<int> intList;

    // Insert elements
    std::cout << "Inserting elements 1 to 5 to the back of the list:\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        intList.InsertBack(i);
    }
    std::cout << "List: " << intList << std::endl;

    // Test circular nature
    std::cout << "\nTesting circular nature (printing 10 elements):\n";
    DCListIterator<int> circularIt(intList);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << circularIt.getData() << " ";
        circularIt.Next();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

DCList.h
#ifndef DCLIST_H
#define DCLIST_H

#include <iostream>

//forward declarations
template <class Type> class DCList;
template <class Type> class DCListIterator;

template <class Type>
class DCListNode {
    friend class DCList<Type>;
    friend class DCListIterator<Type>;
    
    template <class T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DCList<T>& list);

  private:
    Type data;
    DCListNode *next;
    DCListNode *prev;

  public:
    DCListNode(Type element = Type(), DCListNode *n = nullptr, DCListNode *p = nullptr) 
        : data(element), next(n), prev(p) {}
};

template <class Type>
class DCList {
    friend class DCListIterator<Type>;
    
    template <class T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DCList<T>& list);

  public:
    DCList();

    void InsertFront(const Type &item);
    void InsertBack(const Type &item);
    void Insert(DCListNode<Type>* p, DCListNode<Type>* x);

  private:
    DCListNode<Type> *head;  // Head node
};

template <class Type>
class DCListIterator {
  public:
    DCListIterator(const DCList<Type> &l); //constructor
    Type getData() const;
    DCListNode<Type>* Next();
   
  private:
    const DCList<Type> &list;
    DCListNode<Type> *current;
};

// Declaration of the operator<< function
template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DCList<Type>& list);

#include "DCList.tpp"

#endif // DCLIST_H

DCList.tpp
#include <stdexcept>

template <class Type>
DCList<Type>::DCList() {
    head = new DCListNode<Type>();
    head->next = head->prev = head;  // Circular structure
}

template <class Type>
void DCList<Type>::InsertBack(const Type &item) {
    DCListNode<Type>* newNode = new DCListNode<Type>(item);
    Insert(newNode, head);
}

template <class Type>
void DCList<Type>::Insert(DCListNode<Type>* p, DCListNode<Type>* x) {
    p->next = x;
    p->prev = x->prev;
    x->prev->next = p;
    x->prev = p;
}

// Definition of the operator<< function
template <class Type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DCList<Type>& list) {
    DCListNode<Type>* current = list.head->next;
    if (current == list.head) {
        return os << "Empty List";
    }
    while (current != list.head) {
        os << current->data;
        if (current->next != list.head) {
            os << " <-> ";
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return os;
}

// DCListIterator implementations
template <class Type>
DCListIterator<Type>::DCListIterator(const DCList<Type> &l) : list(l), current(l.head->next) {}

template <class Type>
Type DCListIterator<Type>::getData() const {
    return current->data;
}

template <class Type>
DCListNode<Type>* DCListIterator<Type>::Next() {
    current = current->next;
    return current;
}

The issue occurs in the main function when testing the circular nature:
std::cout << "\nTesting circular nature (printing 10 elements):\n";
DCListIterator<int> circularIt(intList);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << circularIt.getData() << " ";
    circularIt.Next();
}

The expected output is
Inserting elements 1 to 5 to the back of the list:
List: 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4 <-> 5

Testing circular nature (printing 10 elements):
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

but the actual output is
Inserting elements 1 to 5 to the back of the list:
List: 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4 <-> 5

Testing circular nature (printing 10 elements):
1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4

As shown above, the list wraps around with an extra trailing zero at the end of the list. Is there something wrong with my data structure? If so, how can I fix it to wrap around from 5 to 1?
Edit: MRE supplied.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

There is lots of irrelevant code in the post. Please try to reduce it to a [mcve]

reducing your code to the minimum will make it much simpler for you to read the code and to debug it. And if you have reduced it to the bare minimum and still cannot spot the issue you have a nice mre to post here

adding ... is not making it a reproducible example. THe code that is now in the question does not compile, hence does not produce wrong output.

A mre is code that others can copy and paste to compile it and see the same output you do.

you can take all the time you need. Often when asked for a mre, users get nervous and vandalize their own question. Rather you should go a step back, into your editor, edit the code, compile it, look at the output, see if the issue persists, repeat this until the issue is gone, then go one iteration back (so the issue is present again), post that code. This can be a matter of hours. Nobody said programming would be simple :P. But its worth the time, because more often than not during that process you will find the issue yourself

For example, in your program you are not using InsertFront so that should be removed. Also try a shorter list than 10 items, and a shorter loop than 15 items. Anything you can do to reduce the amount of code, or simplify the problem, while still reproducing the bug, will help.

Got it, thank you all. Making the MRE now.

@benhpark If I had to guess I would say that your extra node is added when you create the list (i.e. in the list constructor). Your code appears to assume that head is never nullptr so what happens when a list is created?

You are breaking the circular chain at each insertion. See added comments:
// [...]
void DCList<Type>::InsertBack(const Type &item) {
    DCListNode<Type>* newNode = new DCListNode<Type>(item); // newNode prev and next are nullptr
    Insert(newNode, head);
}

template <class Type>
void DCList<Type>::Insert(DCListNode<Type>* p, DCListNode<Type>* x) {
    p->next = x;
    p->prev = x->prev; // x->prev is nullptr
    // p->prev is now nullptr, breaking the cycle
// [...]

This leads later to UB as you somewhat dereference nullptr, which with your compiler and optimisation levels exhibit the unexpected behaviour you observe.
Unrelated: your iterator should adhere to the idiomatic way to define iterators in C++ so one can use iterator_traits.

Here, some reading to go: https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp

Your iterator code does not account for the head node.

Sorry, could you clarify what you meant by iterator code?

I'm surprised it seems I need to explicate DCListNode<Type>* DCListIterator<Type>::Next().

@benhpark https://internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp

That's not an helpful attitude @greybeard. If you can't be bothered to explain, please do not answer questions.
